# File does not exist in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an app which captures images using the camera like this.

```
     String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, galleryPermissions)){
    //Camera
    if (index == 0) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                Uri photoURI = null;

                // N is for Nougat Api 24 Android 7
                if (Build.VERSION_CODES.N <= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
                    // FileProvider required for Android 7.  Sending a file URI throws exception.


                    photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            photoFile);


                    Log.v("highbuild",photoURI.toString());

                } else {
                    // For older devices:
                    // Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" 2 (Samsung GT-P3113 Android 4.2.2, API 17)
                    // Samsung S3
                    photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                    Log.v("lowbuild",photoURI.toString());
                }
                imageuriduplicate = photoURI;
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);
            }
            else{
                Log.v("file", "photo file is null");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Photo file is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    //Gallery
    else if (index == 1) {

        Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickPhoto.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);//one can be replaced with any action code
    }
}

else {
    EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Access for storage",
            101, galleryPermissions);
}
```

My create file image method is like this

```
   private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "AndroidUpload" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    if(!storageDir.exists()){

        boolean s = new File(storageDir.getPath()).mkdirs();

        if(!s){
            Log.v("not", "not created");
        }
        else{
            Log.v("cr","directory created");
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.v("directory", "directory exists");
    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".png",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

I then later save the path to an arraylist and access it.

But when i try to access the file like this

```
                Uri imageuri = Uri.parse(receipts.get(i).imageURI);
                File file = new File(imageuri.getPath());
            if(file.exists()){
                Log.v("exists","file exists");
            }
            else{
                Log.v("no","file doesnt exist");
            }
```

I get the file doesnt exist error.

I have given all the necessary permissions and I am still getting this error. How can fix this?

Comment: An Uri (own resp. Android class?) could contain `"file: ..."`.

Comment: You are not checking the return value of mkdirs(). Further you should check the existense of the file directly. Not after you messed around with a database.

Comment: If mkdirs() returns false you should throw an IOException. Or return null.

Comment: `have given all the necessary permissions `. You as a programmer cant. The user of your app should agree with them.

Comment: Your catch block is empty. Put the usual code in it first. And a Toast displaying e.getMessage(). Then return as it does not make sense to continue then.

Comment: I just checked if the directory exists, it exists, so it didnt have to be created.

Comment: Does not matter. Your code is not reliable. Further you should not try to create the file yourself. The camera app will create the file. You only need an uri. Or filepath. The camera app might think: o that file already exists so i will not overwrite it. You are number #### that uses this shitty code.

Comment: Added to see if there is an IOException. But there isnt any

Comment: You are not seeing exception as your catch block is empty. Please edit your post so we see the real code.

Comment: You should check the existence of the file right after the catch block. And before the intent. And then again in OnActivityResult before you mess around with a database. Or array list.

Comment: I added another check, where if the file is null, it gives me toast. But the file is not null. (Added into the post too)

Comment: this is the image uri i get and which i save- content://com.test.test1.test1.provider/my_images/AndroidUpload20171006_191403_299194039.png

Comment: Your image uri is irrelevant. You should check if the file is created before you try to make an uri for the camera app. And after the camera app is ready you dont also need that uri as you know the file pat.

Comment: I checked if the file is null using that URI, and its not.

Comment: Please do as i told you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the storageDir exists. If not create directories using

```
new File(path_to_dir).mkdirs();
```

Comment: I just added this check - if(!storageDir.exists()){

            new File(storageDir.getPath()).mkdirs();
        }

But i still get the file doesnt exist error.

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs() !!! First check if the directory exists before you try to put a file in it.